# Error: The cursor is invalid for instantiating recordViewCache

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am trying to re-use a class and run it in a job to prove something out.  Here is the job code:

```
InventQuarantineOrder_Scrap scrap = new InventQuarantineOrder_Scrap();
;

scrap.parmInventQuarantineId('00016749_077');
scrap.parmScrapQty(360);
scrap.parmTransDate(Today());

scrap.run();
```

When I run this code, I get the error:

> The cursor is invalid for instantiating recordViewCache

Researching this error led to me this [link](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/axdyntraining/archive/2010/09/21/the-cursor-is-invalid-for-instantiating-recordviewcache), which I tried to implement but I got syntax errors I'm not sure how to fix.  I copied the class and created a new runOnServer method.  But then a validate method doesn't work.  So I modify the validate method to run on the server:

```
static server boolean  validate()
{
     InventQuarantineOrder inventQuarantineOrder =  InventQuarantineOrder::find(inventQuarantineId);
     ;  
     ....    
}
```

Which gave me this error:

> Variable inventQuarantineId has not been declared.

If I comment out the validate() call from the runOnServer method, I get the same error/problem with the inventQuarentineId variable not being declared (it's also used in the run method).

From here, I am not sure how to continue.   What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible to use these methods inside a server method?  Another thing worth noting I think is that I think the job code actually worked, but it did throw 3 lines those "cursor is invalid for instantiating recordViewCache." info alerts.

Comment: You need to use the pack/unpack pattern to transfer the value of the variable from client to server tier. I will write up an answer on this as soon as I find the time (or someone beats me to it).

Answer (score 0):

As you already found out, a `RecordViewCache` can only be used on the server tier. By starting your process in the job on the client tier, the method that creates the `RecordViewCache` (method `viewCacheInventTransId` of table `InventTrans`) is also executed on the client tier, which causes the error. If you put a breakpoint in this method, the call stack in the debugger shows you this:

```
Tier   Method                                                                                                Line
[c]    \Data Dictionary\Tables\InventTrans\Methods\viewCacheInventTransId                                      9
[c]    \Classes\InventMovement\viewCacheInventTransId                                                          7
[s]    \Classes\InventUpd_Financial\initUpdate                                                                14
[s]    \Classes\InventUpd_Financial\newVirtuelQuarantineLoss                                                  19
[c]    \Classes\InventQuarantineOrder_Scrap\run                                                               76
[c]    \Jobs\Job4
```

The solution in the link you gave is for your case a bit more complicated than it needs to be (my comment was my first idea to fix this solution). You just need to create a class with a static server method that executes your job code. You can then call this static server method in your code. Now the debugger will show you the following call stack:

```
Tier   Method                                                                                                Line
[s]    \Data Dictionary\Tables\InventTrans\Methods\viewCacheInventTransId                                      9
[s]    \Classes\InventMovement\viewCacheInventTransId                                                          7
[s]    \Classes\InventUpd_Financial\initUpdate                                                                14
[s]    \Classes\InventUpd_Financial\newInventQuarantineOrder                                                  21
[s]    \Data Dictionary\Tables\InventQuarantineOrder\Methods\startFinancial                                   12
[s]    \Classes\InventQuarantineOrder_Scrap\run                                                               54
[s]    \Classes\Class1\jobOnServer                                                                            10
[c]    \Jobs\Job4                                                                                              5
```